# Regex for excluding lines starting with // from a word counter

Tags: regex

I am building a novel-writing tool that includes in-line annotations designated by "//" a la JavaScript.

I want to be able to count all of the words that don't belong to an annotation (and therefore belong to the 'real' novel) so that a writer can use this to track their word count goals.

For word counts so far, I've been using: `/\S+/g`

I've successfully found a way to exclude full lines with a // prefix with `^(?!\/\/).+$/gm`

But,

1. They don't work together, i.e. `\S+^(?!\/\/).+$/gm`
2. How would I exclude words between a // and the end of a line? i.e. `These words are included.//but these aren't`

Some example text with all cases:

```
// Scene Name - This is a scene description.`
// !Location
// @John @David
Hello, I am very grateful to the Stack Overflow community for teaching me how to fix every problem I've ever had. //wow good content
And here's some more text. This is 30 words.
```

What am I missing?

[Edit: I am using `/\S+/g` for the word count regex, not `/\w+/g`, which counts contractions as two words]

Comment: I think I'd do something like [`var wordCount = str.replace(/\/\/.*/g,'').match(/\b[\w'-]+/g).length;`](http://jsfiddle.net/x1chrb29/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you divide the operation in two, first you replace using the following (simple) regex:

```
/\/\/.*/gm
```

It simply matches any 2 slashes followed by any characters.
Just replace with an empty string. Now you have a nice text without slashes and you can use your word-counting regex to `Count` the Words.

Comment: This won't work if their input is `include me//don't include me`

Comment: Sure it will, it will match from '//' to the end, which is what should be replaced.

Comment: This worked! I used this in combination with bobble bubble's suggestion for the Javascript (and also adjusted my word count regex to \S+g)  `var wordCount = doc.replace(/\/\/.*/gm,'').match(/\S+/g).length;`

Comment: Never mind, I must have misread something. It seems much simpler to match the comments and remove them. I assumed OP did not want to remove the comments, he just didn't want them included in his sample data.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern should be what you need. `^.+?(?=//)|^(?!//).+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UjRiqR/1)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the quick reply! Unfortunately, this isn't also counting the words, and I'm not sure how to fit \w+ in there.

Comment: If you need to count the words after that, you can just split the text on `\s`